# Не могу загрузить картинку для проверки ИИ

Tags: python, tensorflow

У меня такая проблема, я написал ИИ для определения котов и кошек. Обучение модели идет(выводит в консоль эпохи), a после обучение я хочу загрузить картинку для проверки, но не могу.

Вот код:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.utils import load_img, img_to_array


def resize_image(img, label):
  img = tf.cast(img, tf.float32)
  img = tf.image.resize(img, (250, 250))
  img = img / 255.0
  return img, label

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)=tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data(
    path='archive.zip'
)

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
model.compile(optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(), 
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
#print(f'image tensor shape: {tf.get_image(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\2.png").shape}')
# >>> image tensor shape: (1, 784)
tot = model.load_img('kosa.jpg')
tot = np.asarray(tot)
yhat = model.predict(tot)
```

Выдает ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
tot = model.load_img('kosa.jpg') # ???
tot = np.asarray(tot)
yhat = model.predict(tot)
```

А где вы взяли такой код? В [документации](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/load_img) метод `load_img` используется по-другому, он вызывается не от модели:

```
image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(image_path)
input_arr = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(image)
input_arr = np.array([input_arr])  # Convert single image to a batch.
predictions = model.predict(input_arr)
```